# MYSQL session expire with hibernate after a time

Tags: mysql, hibernate

We are working on Hibernate with a MySQL database. We are facing a problem related to the MySQL connection. We are:

1. Starting our web application using tomcat server.
2. Doing some DB work with MySQL using Hibernate.

Now all going well, now the problem is that MySQL has a session timeout for every inactive session, which means all the session connection which we made via any language are refused via MySQL after its configured time. But if a request after that configured time is sent to MySQL it is refused by MySQL and Hibernate is not able to re-connect with it. So every time we need to restart Tomcat.

Is this a Hibernate configuration issue?

Answer (score 0):

Would be nice if you show us your data source connection string, pool configuration and hibernate session factory configuration.

But maybe simply adding parameter autoReconnect to your connection string will solve this.

```
<property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/your_db?autoReconnect=true&amp;allowMultiQueries=true"/>
```